# Removing margin- html

Tags: html, css

I am trying to remove the extra margin- the orange space, and move the red dot up. Could someone please help? I have tried using the css tags- margin, padding. But, could not get it to work.

```html
<div style="padding:0px; margin-right:0px; width: 280; font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif ;font-size: 40px; font-weight: bold;color:#33A8FF">
Current Status 
</div>

<div id= "redC" style="width: 10px;
      height: 10px;
      -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
      -moz-border-radius: 5px;
      border-radius: 5px;
      background: red;
      margin-left: 400px
      ">

</div>
```

[image]

Comment: You can negative margin or merge to two into one with span or other elements.

Comment: @user8446995 If any of answer worked for you, mark as accepted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `display:inline-block` for the both divs.

`div {display:inline-block}`

Answer (score 1):

Use `display:inline-block` and `vertical-align:middle;` to div this will make divs in a line and vertically centered and try to avoid `inline css`

```css
div {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align:middle;
}

.CurrentStatus {
  padding: 0px;
  margin-right: 0px;
  width: 280;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 40px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #33A8FF
}

#redC {
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background: red;
  margin-left: 40px
}
```

```html
<div class="CurrentStatus">
  Current Status
</div>

<div id="redC">

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Method 1)** Insert `display: inline-block` to  `div` like this :

```
div {
   display: inline-block;
}
```

**Method 2)** use of `:after` :

```css
div {
    position: relative;
    padding:0px;
    margin-right:0px;
    width: 280px;
    font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif ;
    font-size: 40px;
    font-weight: bold;
    color:#33A8FF;
}

div:after {
    content: '';
    height: 10px;
    width: 10px;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: red;
    border-radius: 100%;
    top: 50%;
    right: -10px;
}
```

```html
<div>Current Status</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This will work

```html
<div style="padding:0px; margin-right:0px; width: 280; font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif ;font-size: 40px; font-weight: bold;color:#33A8FF; float:left">
Current Status 
</div>

<div id= "redC" style="width: 10px;
      height: 10px;
      -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
      -moz-border-radius: 5px;
      border-radius: 5px;
      background: red;
      float:left;
      margin-top:20px;
     
      ">

</div>
```